# Filling na values with merge from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, fillna

I have a column with na values that I want to fill according to values from another data frame according to a key. I was wondering if there is any simple way to do so.

Example:
I have a data frame of objects and their colors like this:

```
  object   color
0  chair   black
1   ball  yellow
2   door   brown
3   ball     **NaN**
4  chair   white
5  chair     **NaN**
6   ball    grey
```

I want to fill na values in the color column with default color from the following data frame:

```
  object default_color
0  chair         brown
1   ball          blue
2   door          grey
```

So the result will be this:

```
  object   color
0  chair   black
1   ball  yellow
2   door   brown
3   ball     **blue**
4  chair   white
5  chair     **brown**
6   ball    grey
```

Is there any "easy" way to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Look at `pd.Series.map` and `fillna`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create Series and then replace `NaN`s:

```
s = df1['object'].map(df2.set_index('object')['default_color'])
print (s)
0    brown
1     blue
2     grey
3     blue
4    brown
5    brown
6     blue
Name: object, dtype: object
```

```
df1['color']= df1['color'].mask(df1['color'].isnull(), s)
```

Or:

```
df1.loc[df1['color'].isnull(), 'color'] = s
```

Or:

```
df1['color'] = df1['color'].combine_first(s)
```

Or:

```
df1['color'] = df1['color'].fillna(s)
```

---

```
print (df1)
  object   color
0  chair   black
1   ball  yellow
2   door   brown
3   ball    blue
4  chair   white
5  chair   brown
6   ball    grey
```

If unique values in `object`:

```
df = df1.set_index('object')['color']
        .combine_first(df2.set_index('object')['default_color'])
        .reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df = df1.set_index('object')['color']
        .fillna(df2.set_index('object')['default_color'])
        .reset_index()
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `np.where` and mapping by setting a column as index i.e

```
df['color']= np.where(df['color'].isnull(),df['object'].map(df2.set_index('object')['default_color']),df['color'])
```

or `df.where`

```
df['color'] = df['color'].where(df['color'].notnull(), df['object'].map(df2.set_index('object')['default_color']))
```

```
 object   color
0  chair   black
1   ball  yellow
2   door   brown
3   ball    blue
4  chair   white
5  chair   brown
6   ball    grey
```

Comment: Nice one with where.

Comment: Yeah, just giving you guys some space. ;-)

Comment: 8 more reps for my first 10 thousand : 0. Give me some space for next question too :)

Comment: Congrats on 10k :)

Answer (score 5):

Using `loc` + `map`:

```
m = df.color.isnull()
df.loc[m, 'color'] = df.loc[m, 'object'].map(df2.set_index('object').default_color)

df

  object   color
0  chair   black
1   ball  yellow
2   door   brown
3   ball    blue
4  chair   white
5  chair   brown
6   ball    grey
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of these replacements, you should call `set_index` on `df2` just once and save its result.